# Manifest merger failed when adding latest Room (Android Jetpack)

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I am trying to add Android Jetpack Room to an android project.

I added following to app gradle file

```
def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha03"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

which is the latest version of the Room.

But I get following build error, please help!

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

I added lifecycle, viewmodel, navigation, workmanager without any issue though.

after adding

```
'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

get following error

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

---

I am using

- Linux Mint 18.3
- Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: did you try adding tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" in your manifest file?

Comment: @AmitJangid thanks for comment. I already tried it yesterday, updated the question. It seem like a bug to me. downgrading 2.1.0-alpha02 fixes the issue. But alpha03 there brings many bug fixes

Comment: yes quite possible..since it's in alpha version it might have bugs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you use incompatible artifacts in "dependencies" section of app-level `build.gradle` file. Recommended fix: 
`Refactor`->`Migrate to AndroidX...` and then clean and rebuild project.

Alternatively you can replace this in app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

with this:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

add these lines to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and manually fix unresolved references in you code.

Then Sync project -> Clean Project -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Thanks, I did not knew there was a migration option.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error after added this Room depencencies in build.gradle:

```
// Room
def room_version = "2.2.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
// For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
// Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

In Android Studio did:

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart...
3. File -> Sync with File System
4. File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
5. Build -> Rebuild Project
6. Build -> Make Project
7. Deploy

And this done the job.
If ask this is Android Studio 3.3, built December 25 2018.